# Adjectives for "same thing" vs. "same kind of thing"

Tags: selección-de-palabras, adjetivos

In German,

- *das gleiche* refers to

> We both read **the same** (das gleiche)  book (everyone has its own, but they look exactly the same)

- while *das selbe* refers to

> We both read the same book (one book, e.g. sharing, borrowing your book from / lending your book to your friend, the same object)

Does this differentiation exist in Spanish in contrast to English? I only found ***lo mismo***, which is translated as *das selbe/gleiche* in my dictionary. Are there other adjectives that differ between the same object/same kind of object? Or what is the shortest way in Spanish to express this connotation?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's really a duplicate, so I'm not VtCing, but I asked a similar question that may be of interest to you: http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/412/when-to-use-igual-and-lo-mismo

Comment: Very interesting question. I think there is no difference in Spanish but I hope to be wrong =).

Comment: @Flimzy thanks fot the link, preview didn't show this question. But it doesn't seem to answer my question, as *igual* according to the answer has more the meaning of "similar, but different in specific characterics" and *lo mismo* has to be interpreted by context and can mean same thing/kind of thing? **In my question, the distinction is identical, but still different objects and what adjectives to use to express this difference in meaning** *lo mismo* has more the meaning of *same/gleiche* in my opinion.

Answer (score 7):

As others have stated "*leímos el libro*" is always ambiguous. However you could use "*leímos el mismo ejemplar del libro*" or "*leímos la misma copia del libro*" if you want to express what *das selbe* means.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such distinction in the Spanish language, where to achieve the difference in concept present in German (*gleich / selbst*) you must use other means:

- Dealing with books you can state de difference between `libro` (the phisical copy) and `obra` (what is actually read at last):

> *Leímos el mismo libro*.  →  (possible ambiguity)
>   *Leímos la misma obra.*  →  (a bit more clear)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly the differentiation, *das gleiche* would refer to things that belong to the same genre, or that are equal in some respect, while *das selbe* points to true identity (same individual). I don't think there is a word, not even a well stablished expression, to convey this (important) nuance in Spanish: "[**el mismo**](http://buscon.rae.es/dpdI/SrvltGUIBusDPD?lema=mismo)" (determinate) (or "**lo mismo**" - undeterminate) is used both for identity or for equality. The adjective "**idéntico**" doesn't help, either; it doesn't  implies individual identity (rather on the contrary, I'd say: it normally emphasizes a great similarity.. between two different individuals). So, the expression

> Ella y yo leímos el mismo libro.

is hopelessly ambiguous. If I'd want to clarify that I'm not meaning just the same novel, but the same book, materially speaking... I'd say so:

> Ella y yo leímos el mismo libro, materialmente hablando.